# Github actio to create a html file in the main branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have copied/closed this repository (https://github.com/staticwebdev/vanilla-basic).

Now I want to create a `HTML` (let's call it `dummy.html`) in the `src` folder of this repo with the content as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Vanilla JavaScript App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
    <h1>Customer Approval Page</h1>
    <h2> <customer name> </h2>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

I found these 2 actions but they are not working for me. Can anyone help?

https://github.com/DamianReeves/write-file-action

https://github.com/1arp/create-a-file-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with this workflow:

```yaml
name: so-037-create-file

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465583/github-actio-to-create-a-html-file-in-the-main-branch

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Overwrite file
        uses: "DamianReeves/write-file-action@master"
        with:
          path: src/dummy.html
          write-mode: preserve 
          contents: |
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
                <title>Vanilla JavaScript App</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <main>
                <h1>Customer Approval Page</h1>
                <h2> <customer name> </h2>
                </main>
            </body>
            </html>     
            
      - name: Commit & Push
        uses: Andro999b/push@v1.3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: main
          force: true
          message: 'Overwritten by Github Actions - ${date}'
```

and it works.

Folder before the run:
[image]
Folder after the run:
[image]

Here is the link to [the file](https://github.com/kmadof/github-actions-manual/blob/main/src/dummy.html).